# How to stop OWA redirect

Tags: asp.net, exchange-server, iis-10

We have a website application that is the /AppName on our domain. I'm using URL rewrite to go to that app. Exchange is also install on the server and it's OWA takes the https of our site. I want that to go to /AppName instead. How do I do this?

I've changed the logon.aspx to be a redirect, but this feels like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

*I would highly recommend not to install something else on your Exchange server. If this solution has a vulnerability somebody from external can take over your whole Exchange environment. I would go for a separate server.*

However, to answer your question check / change the following:

1. Start IIS Manager.
2. Expand the local computer, expand Sites, and then click Default Web Site.
3. At the bottom of the Default Web Site Home pane, click Features View if this option isn't already selected.
4. In the IIS section, double-click HTTP Redirect.
5. Remove the Redirect requests to this destination check box.

More infos [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998359(v=exchg.150).aspx).